# Why is $\sum\limits_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r\Delta D}{(1 + r)^t} = \Delta D$?

Tags: summation, infinity, economics, infinite-product

In a book on economics, I have read that $\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r\Delta D}{(1 + r)^t} = \frac{r\Delta D}{r} = \Delta D$.

$t$ is the index of the current time period; $r$ represents the interest rate; $\Delta D$ is the change of debts.

Why can this equation be solved like this? Let’s say $r = 2$. Then, $\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2 \Delta D}{(1 + 2)^t}$ should result in something like $\frac{2\Delta D}{3}$, shouldn’t it?

What am I getting wrong here? Why does $\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1 + r)^t} = \frac{r}{r}$?

Comment: That naughty economics book!  It assumes readers know about the geometric series!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a constructive comment?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r\Delta D}{(1 + r)^t}=\\r\Delta D \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + r)^t}=\\ $$ now note that $$r>0 \to r+1>1 \\\to
0<\frac{1}{1+r}<1$$
now see whats the value of $\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + r)^t}$ let it's name be $S=\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + r)^t}$
$$S= \frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^2}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^3}+...$$multiply  $S$ by $\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}$ so 
$$\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}S=\frac{1}{(1 + r)^2}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^3}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^4}+...$$ no look at $S-\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}S$ 
$$S-\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}S=\\
(\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^2}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^3}+...)-(\frac{1}{(1 + r)^2}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^3}+\frac{1}{(1 + r)^3}+...) \\ \to S-\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}S=\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}$$simpllify
$$S(1-\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1})=\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}\\
S(\frac{1+r-1}{(1 + r)^1})=\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}\\\to \\
S=\frac{\frac{1}{(1 + r)^1}}{\frac{r}{(1 + r)^1}}=\frac1r$$now look at begining
$$\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r\Delta D}{(1 + r)^t}=\\r\Delta D \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + r)^t}=\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r\Delta D}{(1 + r)^t}=\\r\Delta D S=\\r\Delta D \times\color{red} {\frac1r}\\=\Delta D $$

Answer (score 1):

The main theme here is the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=0}^\infty q^t=\frac{1}{1-q}\qquad\qquad |q|<1
\end{align*}

Since OPs series starts with index $t=1$ we consider
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=1}^\infty q^t&=\left(\sum_{t=0}^\infty q^t\right)-1\\
&=\frac{1}{1-q}-1\\
&=\frac{q}{1-q}\qquad\qquad |q|<1\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Using (1) we can transform OPs series
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{t=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+r)^t}&=\sum_{t=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^t
> =\frac{\frac{1}{1+r}}{1-\frac{1}{1+r}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{r}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   valid for $\left|\frac{1}{1+r}\right|<1$.

Putting all together we conclude from (2) the following is valid for 
$\left|\frac{1}{1+r}\right|<1$:

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r\Delta D}{(1 + r)^t}&=r\Delta D\cdot\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+r)^t}\\
> &=r\Delta D\cdot\frac{1}{r}\\
> &=\Delta D\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

With respect to the example $r=2$: Since $\left|\frac{1}{1+2}\right|=\frac{1}{3}<1$ we obtain according to (2)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2\Delta D}{(1 + 2)^t}&=2\Delta D\cdot\sum_{t = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^t\\
&=2\Delta D\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\Delta D
\end{align*}
in accordance with (3).

Answer (score 0):

$$r > 0 \implies \frac{1}{1+r} < 1$$

then use GP.

For $|x| < 1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}$$